# Apple Pay Payment Token Example

Tags: json, base64, checkout, applepay

How can I somehow obtain an example of an Apple Pay Payment Token ([as described here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PaymentTokenJSON/PaymentTokenJSON.html)) without actually requesting a payment from Apple using an Apple Device?

I am creating an endpoint that will accept the Apple Pay payment token exactly as it is received on the device requesting payment from Apple. However, it is a binary data and it will thus have to be decoded into what I assume is a normal json object. What would the format/structure of this json object be?

From Checkout.com's documentation on Apple Pay ([here](https://docs.checkout.com/docs/apple-pay#section-request-example)) I would assume the decoded json object looks something like this (although they mark it as an "example", so I can't be sure):

```
{
  "type": "applepay",
  "token_data": {
    "version": "EC_v1",
    "data": "t7GeajLB9skXB...",
    "signature": "MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAq...",
    "header": {
      "ephemeralPublicKey": "MFkwEwYHKoZIzj...",
      "publicKeyHash": "tqYV+tmG9aMh+l/K6cicU...",
      "transactionId": "3cee89679130a4b2617c..."
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the data in the fields above were shortened for brevity.

**What is the exact object/data that Apple sends the device requesting payment?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed to figure out what Apple sends as a payment token.

Apple sends a binary data (`PKPaymentToken`) that can be decoded into json. The json object looks as follows:

```
{
    "data":"...",
    "signature":"...",
    "version":"..",
    "header":{
        "applicationData":"...",
        "ephemeralPublicKey":"...",
        "wrappedKey":"...",
        "publicKeyHash":"...",
        "transactionId":"..."
    }
}
```

Using the payment token thus first requires decoding the binary data into json, which can then be sent to a merchant (like Checkout or Stripe). It should be noted that some of the fields in the json object are encrypted. They may be used unencrypted or encrypted. [Checkout, for instance, accepts the encrypted fields](https://docs.checkout.com/docs/apple-pay#section-body-parameters).

**The token**

> **data**: payment data dictionary, Base64 encoded as a string
>
> **header**: header dictionary
>
> **signature**: detached PKCS #7 signature, Base64 encoded as string
>
> **version**: string

**Header**

> **applicationData**: SHA–256 hash, hex encoded as a string
>
> **ephemeralPublicKey**: X.509 encoded key bytes, Base64 encoded as a string
>
> **wrappedKey**: A Base64 encoded string
>
> **publicKeyHash**: SHA–256 hash, Base64 encoded as a string
>
> **transactionId**: A hexadecimal identifier, as a string

More information/detail can be found in [the Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PaymentTokenJSON/PaymentTokenJSON.html).

Comment: do you have an example how to send this decrypted data to Stripe?

Comment: @ElmarAbdurayimov nope, sorry. But you can have a look at Stripe's documentation... it should be pretty similar.

Comment: Hey @AnonymousAngelo , stuck in similar scenario. Got the `PKPaymentToken` but now how to decrypt it in json to send to Checkout.com? I can't understand Apple docs